# Android document reader and writer

Tags: android

How can I implement a document reader sample app?

I have a requirement in which I have to read and write documents.

Tried to view the document:

```
WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
wv.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
wv.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
String pdfURL = "http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37098169/Course%20Brochures/AND101.pdf";
wv.loadUrl(someurl + pdfURL);
```

Also, I've tried reading a file from my directory and tried to open it with default editors but I have to save the edited file and send it to server and should not maintain any copy of it.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Help Desk Voice Flow.doc");

try {
    if (file.exists()) {
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent objIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        // replace "application/msword" with
        // "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
        // for docx files
        // objIntent.setDataAndType(path,"application/msword");
        objIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(objIntent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MyClass.this, "File NotFound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(MyClass.this, "No Viewer Application Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: why down votes?

Comment: Because this question is way too broad and will soon be closed as such.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use webview to render .doc file i your screen coming from the server.

Comment: thanks for the reply do u mean that I somehow open the file in a webview?
then how would I edit it if I want to

Comment: You will not be able to edit in Web View . To edit the .doc file you will have to open it using any app inbuilt in device . And then using intent start that app and pass .doc file as parameter in and start the intent.

Comment: @PraveenVishal How can you view the .doc file directly in your webview, I don't think so this is possible. When you try to do it just download the file.

Answer (score 0):

Wow ! It's a big ask. I would recommend to you to forget about android, and think about a document reader and writer in general. You need to first of all, sketch the skeleton of such an application. How it should work ? Is viewing and editing the only features needed ? What about sharing or downloading ? Moreover, just viewing/editing can be a big problem : What happens in case of parallel editing ? What happens in offline mode ? .... and many more.

Its like a general system design question that usually interviewing companies ask. You need to take step one by one, firstly, prototyping -> designing -> modelling -> proof of concept -> implementation -> testing -> maintaining ... (phew...)

What you are asking is implementation phase that too in android, so, it comes in late, first sketch your idea, model it properly, later while implementation if any problem arrives, stackoverflow to the rescue.

Hope it helps somehow !

Comment: thanks for the reply,do I have any library for it..I just need to see first that it is possible or not then worry about all the other usecases

Comment: Definitely its possible ! Take an example of Google Docs, it does exactly you have asked for. Yes, there are many libraries for android, mostly they are generic viewers, eg : https://github.com/sitewaerts/android-document-viewer, https://github.com/mthli/Knife  ...many more. Just Search : 'android document editor github' on google. Hope this helps !

Comment: @AbhinavPuri Can you suggest me any concrete solution to be integrated with Android Platform. I have tried lots of solutions but all is vain. Almost solutions are paid like aspose.words, SmartOffice, LeadTools. I also tried Apache Poi, but is very complex and have hugh number of jars to integrate and have dependencies issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File tempFile = new File(cDir.getPath() + "/document.txt");

FileWriter writer = null;

try {
    writer = new FileWriter(tempFile);
    writer.write(js.toString());
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

FileReader fReader = null;
BufferedReader bReader = null;
try {
    fReader = new FileReader(tempFile);
    bReader = new BufferedReader(fReader);

    while ((strLine = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(strLine);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is just to open the text file.